# Stuck while installing the Review Board on Fedora 20

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server, fedora

This is the screen shot where I was stuck here. No idea what to do ?
I have already given all the required permission as listed below, and also created the directory which was mentioned in screenshot .

```
chown -R apache /var/www/reviews.example.com/htdocs/media/uploaded
chown -R apache /var/www/reviews.example.com/data
chown -R apache /var/www/reviews.example.com/htdocs/media/ext
chown -R apache /var/www/reviews.example.com/htdocs/static/ext
chown -R apache /var/www/reviews.example.com/htdocs/media/uploaded
chmod -R 644 /var/www/reviews.example.com/htdocs/media/uploaded

ln -s /var/www/reviews.example.com/conf/apache-wsgi.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/reviewboard-sitename.conf
```

I am using Fedora 20. Can someone suggest me what to do next ? All installation steps are followed from https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/2.0/admin/installation/linux/ this website.[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting the webserver as it says?

Comment: yes I had restarted web server so many time by using this command

systemctl restart httpd.service  still result is same